# calculating sum and parsing first table's variables to another page

Tags: php, mysqli, get, sum

The Problem: Trying to calculate sum of a total variable which is inside the table invoicesub in the Form Process (2nd page). Trying to make the sum(total) appear in 3rd page which is display_invoice and also get the customer_name in the form process page(2nd page). somehow $_get["$cust_name"]; is not working and im getting a blank from it. Next, after i can get the sum_total variable how do i parse all these to the 4th page using a form?

Edit:http://imageshack.com/a/img19/8729/btls.png (picture of output)
http://imageshack.com/a/img20/8744/s3ut.png (picture of my database)
Too low rep, i cant post images. I uploaded it to image shack. The 1 on top of the table is from the mysqli_num_rows. This is the first row i entered in the form page. The 2nd row is missing

edit:
New Invoicefinal

```
echo "<table border='1'>\n";
echo "<tr>\n";
echo "<th>Services Rendered</th>\n";
echo "<th>Quantity</th>\n";
echo "<th>Price($)</th>\n";
echo "<th>Discount(%)</th>\n";
echo "<th>Amount</th>\n";
echo "</tr>";

$cname = $_GET["cname"];

global $connection;

$sql1="SELECT description,quantity, amount, discount, total, SUM(total) as sumtotal FROM invoicesub WHERE cust_name='$cname' GROUP BY description ORDER BY id";
$result2 = mysqli_query($connection, $sql1) or die(mysqli_error($connection));


echo $count;
while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)){
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $rows['description'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $rows['quantity'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $rows['amount'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $rows['discount']. "%" . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" ."$". $rows['total']  . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";



          }         
          echo "</table>";
          ?>





          <?php
          $sql1="SELECT SUM(total) as total_amt FROM invoicesub WHERE cust_name='$cname'";
$result3 = mysqli_query($connection, $sql1) or die(mysqli_error($connection));

          while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result3)){

          echo "<tr>";
          echo "<td>". "Total Amount:" ."$". $rows['total_amt']  . "</td>";
          echo "</tr>";

          echo "<form action=\"4thpage.php\" method=\"POST\">";
          echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"total_amt\"/>";
          echo "Customer Paid:";
          echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"paid\" value=\"\"/>";

          echo "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit\" value=\"Submit\"/>";
          echo "<input type=\"button\" value=\"Cancel\" onclick=\"window.location='manage_content.php';\"/>";
          echo "</form>";

          }
```

The Form: It consists of a form that can allow more than 1 row of inputs, which means i will have more than 2 descriptions, quantity, amount and discount. Thus, i put them inside an array

Form Process: This is the 2nd page, it will take in all the arrays parsed in, make a loop to insert all the inputted variables in the form into the table invoicesub.

Display_invoice: This is the 3rd page, i want to show all the customer_name, descriptions, quantity, amount, total_amt that was keyed into invoicesub and then do a sum(total) and show it at the bottom of the page. I also want to insert the customer_name, sum(total) variable into the fourth page through the form at display_invoice. Is this possible?

Form

```
function addTextArea(){
count= count+1;
var div = document.getElementById('name');
div.innerHTML += "<div> <input type='text' name='name[]' value='' "+"id=name"+count+"> </div>";
div.innerHTML += "\n<br />";
var div = document.getElementById('quantity');
div.innerHTML += "<div><input type='text' name='quantity[]' value ='' "+"id=quantity"+count+"></div>";
div.innerHTML += "\n<br />";
var div = document.getElementById('amount');
div.innerHTML += "<div><input type='text' name='amount[]'  value ='' "+"id=amount"+count+"></div>";
div.innerHTML += "\n<br />";
var div = document.getElementById('discount');
div.innerHTML += "<div><input type='text' name='discount[]'  value ='' "+"id=discount"+count+"></div>";
div.innerHTML += "\n<br />";
}

function removeTextArea(){
document.getElementById("name"+count).remove();

document.getElementById("quantity"+count).remove();

document.getElementById("amount"+count).remove();

document.getElementById("discount"+count).remove();
count = count-1;
}

</script>


</head>

<body>

<form  action="invoiceprocess.php" method="POST">
<?php
echo "<table border='2'>\n"; 
echo "<tr>\n"; 
echo "<th>Description</th>\n"; 
echo "<th>Quantity</th>\n"; 
echo "<th>Amount($)</th>\n";
echo "<th>Discount(%)</th>\n";
echo "</tr>"; 

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>"?><input type='text' size="50" name='name[]' value='Examination and Consultation' readonly/><?php "</td>";
echo "<td>"?><input type='text' size="50" name='quantity[]' value='' /><?php "</td>";
echo "<td>"?><input type='text' size="50" name='amount[]' value='' /><?php "</td>";
echo "<td>"?><input type='text' size="50" name='discount[]' value='' /><?php "</td>";
echo "</tr>";

echo "<tr>"; 
echo "<td>"?><div id="name"></div> <?php "</td>"; 
echo "<td>"?><div id="quantity"></div> <?php "</td>"; 
echo "<td>"?><div id="amount"></div> <?php "</td>"; 
echo "<td>"?><div id="discount"></div> <?php "</td>"; 
echo "</tr>";
?>
Customer Name:
<br />
<input type="text" name="cust_name" value="" /> &nbsp;
<br />
<input type="button" value="Add Description" onClick="addTextArea();"> &nbsp;


<input type="button" value="Remove Description" onClick="removeTextArea();"> &nbsp;
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">

</form>

</body>
```

invoiceprocess (The 2nd page)

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){ // Process the form
    $name_array = $_POST['name'];
    $quantity_array = $_POST['quantity'];
    $amount_array = $_POST['amount'];
    $discount_array = $_POST['discount'];
    $cust_name_array = mysql_prep( $_POST['cust_name']);
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($name_array); $i++){
        $cust_name = $cust_name_array;
        $name = $name_array[$i];
        $quantity = $quantity_array[$i];
        $amount = $amount_array[$i];
        $discount = $discount_array[$i];
        $total_amt = ($amount - ($amount * ($discount / 100))) * $quantity;

            global $connection;
            $query = "INSERT INTO invoicesub (";
            $query.= " cust_name, description, quantity, amount, discount, total";
            $query.= ") VALUES (";
            $query.= " '{$cust_name}', '{$name}', {$quantity}, {$amount}, {$discount}, {$total_amt}";
            $query.= ")";

            $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);


        }         
       redirect_to("invoicesubmitfinal.php?cname=".urlencode($cust_name));

        }
```

Display_Invoice(invoicesubmitfinal.php)

```
    echo "<table border='1'>\n";
        echo "<tr>\n";
    echo "<th>Customer_name</th>\n";
        echo "<th>Description</th>\n";
        echo "<th>Quantity</th>\n";
        echo "<th>Amount($)</th>\n";
        echo "<th>Discount(%)</th>\n";
        echo "<th>Total_amt</th>\n";
        echo "</tr>";

$cust_name = $_GET["$cust_name"];

global $connection;

$sql1="SELECT SUM(total) FROM invoicesub WHERE cust_name='$cust_name'";
$result2 = mysqli_query($connection, $sql1) or die(mysqli_error($connection));

while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)){
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $rows['quantity'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $rows['amount'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $rows['discount']. "%" . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" ."$". $rows['total']  . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . "$" . $total_amt . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";



        <form action="insertfinal.php" method="POST">

        Customer Paid:
        <input type="text" name="paid" value="" />

        </form>
```

Comment: replace `$cust_name = $_GET["$cust_name"];` with `$cust_name = $_GET["cust_name"];` ?

Comment: Wow, too many questions, for one it's `$_GET['cname'];` Can you please explain your second problem, you want this customer name to be passed to another form? Your `invoicesubmitfinal` and `Display_Invoice` are two different pages?

Comment: Sorry my bad, invoicesubmitfinal is display_invoice. so sorry, ill change the title of the 3rd page now to avoid confusion

Comment: i used echo $_GET["$cname"];
but i got a blank screen with a empty table

Comment: @user3340777 Your `invoicesubmitfinal.php?cname` cname does not have a `$` sign, so you do not place it in your `$_GET`. Remove the `$` and try exactly `$_GET['cname'];`

Comment: ooh i see, thanks. Now i still have a partial empty table though

Comment: Any errors showing up? Can you `echo $cust_name;` and try that with the query in your phpMyAdmin?

Comment: ok, it's all working now. i forgot to assign the $get_[cname] to the $cname. 

Problem i encounter is that it only prints 1 row out of the 2 rows i keyed in.

Comment: `SUM(total)` will be printing only one row, maybe you need to use `GROUP by` clause, could you paste your test data and needed output?

Comment: i did a mysql num rows and found out that 
$sql1="SELECT SUM(total) as sumtotal, description, quantity,amount,discount,total FROM invoicesub WHERE cust_name='$cname'";
$result2 = mysqli_query($connection, $sql1) or die(mysqli_error($connection));
only gives out 1 row. How do i make it print out all the rows for that cname?

Comment: Test Data is 
2 rows. 
Description1 is Consultation
Description2 is asd
Quantity1 is 1
quantity2 is 1 
amount1 is 1
amount2 is 1 
discount1 is 0
discount2 is 0 

just that, 
my output currently is 
consultation, 1, 1, 0 , 1, 2 
in the form of description, quantity, amount, discount, totalamt, sum(total)

Comment: Shouldn't your query be like: `SELECT quantity, amount, discount, total, SUM(total) as total_amt FROM invoicesub WHERE cust_name='$cust_name' GROUP BY cust_name` ?

Comment: yep changed to your query, but it is still printing only 1 row. I checked the database, there are 2 rows. How do i print the other row?

Comment: Can you please edit your question and print a screenshot or the values  that you have in your table?

Comment: done. somehow the query only returns 1 rows which is strange

Comment: Sorry, my bad, got a bit confused, instead of `GROUP BY cust_name` try `GROUP BY description`

Comment: YES! now it prints both rows. However, how do i get the sum_total thing from outside the while loop ? I want to print the total_amt variable outside of the loop, it is possible ?

Comment: Yes, you can write another query that only has `SUM(total)` outside the loop and print it

Comment: erm, if i want to parse the cname and the sum(total) variable to the 4th page, should i use a form ? Or is there a better way to parse all these variables to the 4th page?

Comment: Yes, you need to use a form. If you do not want them to be displayed on the 3rd page you can put them in `<input type="hidden"` tag or you can also pass it as a `$_GET` parameter but that's unsafe.

Comment: i added in the form, this is what my invoicesubmitfinal looks like now. I put it under edit in the question as New invoicefinal.

Comment: I also have another question, how do i delete everything inside invoicesub, and transfer them to another table called displaybilling. (display billing is unrelated to the 4th page)?  I wish to make it so that on clicking the submit button, it will transfer all the files inside invoicesub to displaybilling and then also parse the total_amt variable as well as the cname to the 4th page.

Comment: Are `insertfinal` and `invoicefinal` the same? So you want the customer name to be passed, you can do this way, in `display_invoice` add this hidden input tag `<input type="hidden" name="cname" value="<?php echo $_GET['cname']" />` and in `invoicefinal.php` you can retrieve it `$_POST['cname']` . As for your second comment, please open up a new question since it's a different problem altogether and requires more details.

Comment: erm insertfinal is the 4th page. i've done as you asked and asked on the transferring of table thing on another question

Comment: Erm sorry, im a newbie, which content should i show for my 2nd question? I think it is abit confusing for those who want to help? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21965412/transferring-contents-of-tables-and-parsing-variables-of-table-to-the-next-page
this is the link of my other question. How should i go about asking? Sorry im kind of desperate to finish this assignment as it is due tomorrow >.<